# jquery substring based on many separated characters

Tags: jquery, substring

I'm looking for a easy and effective method of splitting a id string into many variables based on a separating character.

eg.

```
var id = "12.34.red.blue.1253";
var sub1 = id.substr(0, id.indexOf('.'));

//then what for the following substrings?
```

Desired Result

```
sub1 = 12
sub2 = 34
sub3 = red 
sub4 = blue
sub5 = 1253
```

Comment: You can use the JavaScript split() function http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
 var sub = id.split('.');
```

This will create this

```
 sub = ["12", "34", "red", "blue", "1253"];
```

You can print it out like this:

```
 for(i=0;i<sub.length;i++){
       alert(sub[i]);
 }
```

Comment: Cant believe I over-looked split, thanks for the prompt and well explained answer!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `substr` you can use `split`.

```
var id = "12.34.red.blue.1253";

var sub = id.split('.');

sub[0] = 12
sub[1] = 34
.
.
.
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

> The split() method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings.